# iFrame loading my shopping cart requires a cookie to be sent through to display cart contents; Safari blocking the cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, iframe, woocommerce, safari

Works perfectly on Chrome & Firefox, but has major issues when attempting to load in Safari. The whole premise is that we want have the entire shopping experience done through said iFrame on a secondary URL, and then direct to the primary URL once the user reaches the checkout page (for security reasons).

I'm using WooCommerce as our shopping cart, built on top of WordPress. I have limited knowledge of web languages, but I know enough to piece together code that I find on the internet to make things work most of the time. All of the info I find about the third-party cookie issues with Safari date back to 2012/13, and most don't seem to make any difference. For the moment, I've written some JS to redirect to the cart on the primary domain if Safari is detected:

```js
 <script>
    var is_safari = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") > -1;
    var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') > -1;
    if ((is_chrome) && (is_safari)) {is_safari = false;}  
    if (is_safari) {
        if (!document.cookie.match(/^(.*;)?\s*woocommerce_cart_hash\s*=\s*[^;]+(.*)?$/)) {
            document.cookie = 'fixed=fixed; expires=Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC; path=/';
            window.location.replace("primarydomain.com");
        }
    }
</script>
```

It's made from a piece I found on GitHub that aims to fix the issue by pre-loading the page in order to snag the cookie, and then once the cookie is found to reload the iFrame since Safari already has access to the cookie. The problem is, even when the cookie already exists, it's like Safari refuses to acknowledge that it's there and still loads a blank/empty shopping cart (the cookie is titled "woocommerce_cart_hash").

Am I ignorant by trying to fix this? Or am I looking in the wrong place? All help is greatly appreciated, thanks.